# How to enable/get OpenGL 3.1?

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I have a rather old laptop, which has a Intel Core duo 2 processor
and I was not able to run the Dolphin Emulator or any games from steam that I wanted because I needed a minimum of OpenGL 3.1 .

I ran the oibaf PPA and now I have Mesa 11.2 installed

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0-devel (git-56fc298 2016-01-12 wily-oibaf-ppa)
```

is there a possibility to upgrade my OpenGl version to 3.1?
and if yes which steps do i have to take. (pls give me commands :D )

In addition, i'd like to ask if i need to take any more steps so that these error messages won't show up, or will they be solved once I run OpenGL 3.1?

```
GPU: OGL ERROR: Need OpenGL version 3.
GPU: Does your video card support OpenGL 3?

GPU: OGL ERROR: Need GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object.
GPU: Does your video card support OpenGL 3.1?

GPU: OGL ERROR: Need at least GLSL 1.30
GPU: Does your video card support OpenGL 3.0?
GPU: Your driver supports GLSL 1.20

Failed to compile vertex shader: /home/jannis/.local/share/dolphin-emu/Dump/bad_vs_0000.txt
Debug info (Intel Open Source Technology Center, Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset , 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0-devel (git-56fc298 2016-01-12 wily-oibaf-ppa)):
0:1(10): error: GLSL 1.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES
```

Comment: Simple, you're going to need newer hardware

Comment: If your GPU does not support OpenGL 3.1 it's a no-go.

Comment: s/your GPU/your driver/

Answer (score 6):

well maybe your hardware does not support OpenGL 3.1+, but there is a workaround. You can use Software Rendering (LLVMpipe). In order to do that you have to run:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 *command*
```

where *command* is your program of choice. Example:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxgears
```

On steam you should put in Right Click on Game->Properties->Set Launch Options

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 %command%
```

However the games might (and will) run slow! It is strongly recommended to
buy a new laptop/ update your graphics card.

At this point of time LLVMpipe supports up to OpenGL 3.3.(NOTE: i have Ubuntu 14.04 and lower mesa version than you)

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that your system does not have OpenGL 3.1 installed, the issue is that your graphics card does not support OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but thanks to MS with its DX10/11, the sentence «graphic card does not support» could confuse — it is rather driver doesn't support, not the card itself.